# Deleting old documents based on timestamp through Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete specific document in the collection based on timestamp of that document. Posts that are out of date I set them to, should be deleted from the cloud on the script call.

The problem is that I couldn't manage to find a way to iterate over all the documents in the collection, so that I can access the fields and compare `Date.now()` to `post['expireDate]`.

I'm not using the realtime database, but the firestore cloud for my project. I've found a way to do it in the db, but no on the cloud, and have tried different ways to do it.

```
exports.removeOldPosts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const timeNow = Date.now();
    let postsRef = admin.firestore().collection('accesories/').listDocuments();

    postsRef.forEach(post => {
        if (post['expiredDate'] < timeNow) {
            post.delete();
        }
    })

    return res.status(200).end();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the [`listDocuments()` API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments), which returns (asynchronously) a list of document references. But your code :

- does not deal with the fact that the call is asynchronous. I.e. you don't have a `then()` callback, as in the example of the documentation.
- assumes that the data of the document is retrieved, while `listDocuments` in reality only returns document **references**.

To fix this, I recommend using the `get()` API that is shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection). You'll still have to deal with the asynchronous nature yourself though, even with that API, so I recommend studying up on the asynchronous nature of Cloud Functions and modern web APIs. One placeto get started could be Doug's excellent blog post [Why are the Firebase API asynchronous?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) and video series [Learn JavaScript Promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA).

---

As a separate note: instead of reading all documents from the database, and then determining in your code which ones to delete, I'd recommend [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to only retrieve the documents that you want to delete. This leads to reading fewer documents, which saves you some cost in both `document reads` and `bandwidth`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out asap

Comment: It works like magic now, thank you for your detailed answer, It was my first time using JS, and I didn't know you could do async programming on the cloud, that was my first mistake to begin with :)